# How to Insert Data in multiple tables linked by a foreign key in Java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Table Name:

> CUSTOMER_INFORMATION

1. Customer_ID (PK)
2. Customer_Name
3. Mobile_Number

> EVENT_INFORMATION

1. Event_ID (PK)
2. Event_Name

> RELATION_TABLE

1. Event_ID (FK)
2. Customer_ID (FK)

Comment: Hi, asking for a complete solution like that will likely attract negative votes. Why don't you try and write some code, troubleshoot any issues you may encounter, and then share the results? Someone will surely help you. If you don't know where to start, review JPA/Hibernate tutorials online. Also, please have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

First You will have to add records in CUSTOMER_INFORMATION, EVENT_INFORMATION tables

**Insert into CUSTOMER_INFORMATION table**

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_INFORMATION VALUES (123,'new user','+923417874563');
```

**Insert into EVENT_INFORMATION table**

```
INSERT INTO EVENT_INFORMATION VALUES (456,'new event');
```

**Now we can add new record in the RELATION_TABLE by using above primary keys**

```
INSERT INTO RELATION_TABLE VALUES (456,123);
```

But there must be some information in the RELATION_ABLE that escribes the relation. and primary key of the relation table